# AWS Contigo - authenticate to Google on my Flutter app

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, authentication

I'm trying to implement Login Screen with Flutter that will authenticate with Google throw AWS Contigo authentication.

I'm using this library with Cognito's federated sign-in on mobile devices. I'm using flutter_webview to navigate to Cognito's authorized URL. Use flutter_webview's navigationDelegate to catch the redirect from the Google app. then I should make a POST request to Cognito's token URL to get your tokens. Create the session and user with the tokens.

I'm not sure what I should add in the redirect to Google?

```
https://${COGNITO_POOL_URL}" +
        ".amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=" +
        "${COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}&code=" + authCode + "&redirect_uri=myapp://WHAT TO ADD HERE??";
```

Thank you.